# Why the error C2248 when the copy constructor is private in the code below?

Tags: c++, private-methods, rvo

This code emits `error C2248: 'A::A' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'` in VS2010, although RVO doesn't need a copy constructor. To prove this, just turn public the declaration `A(const A&);` below, and the code will execute without a problem, even without a definition for the copy constructor .

```
class A
{
    int i;
    A(const A&);

    public:
    A() : i(1) {}

};

A f() { return A(); }

int main()
{
    A a;
    a = f();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because your program doesn't end up actually invoking the copy constructor does not mean it is permissible to omit it.  Declaring but not defining it just "tricks" the compiler by making the function available during compilation but not during linking, so once the call to it is optimized out, everything "works."  But RVO is an optimization for performance, and your program must be written such that it is correct without the presence of RVO.

Comment: But RVO is always applied in MS compilers, even in debug builds. So in this case, the compiler knows that the copy constructor isn't necessary.

Comment: I guess a quote from The Standard would be useful here.

Comment: @sharptooth: Do *you* really need it? :) From C++03: 3.2p2 *A copy constructor is used even if the call is actually elided by the implementation.* 12.8p14  *A program is ill-formed if the copy constructor or the copy assignment operator for an object is implicitly used and the special member function is not accessible (clause 11).*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes, I do - it's often easier to just blame everything on the language.

Comment: @sharptooth: At any rate there you have the relevant quotes. You can probably locate the same text in C++11 somewhere around those sections

Comment: @sharptooth Have you located the text in C++11?

Comment: @user1042389: Nope, I don't have access to the text.